# Maven clean package produces two jars

Tags: maven, deployment, jar

I packaged my java application using `mvn clean package`. This produced two jars in my `target` directory - one is `myapp-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the other is `myapp-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar`.

Can someone explain the difference between these two?

If I want to deploy my application to a server which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myapp-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar` contains all your source code along with your project, during development it is easier to debug when the sources are attached. It is most likely generated by the `maven-source-plugin`. You will likely find it configured in your `pom.xml`. When deploying, use the other jar: `myapp-0.1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`